# Create OCGs for each character in a document

Tags: pdf, ocg

I need an ocg for each character in the pdf-export to be able to import the pdf in after effects with each character as a separate layer. I'm looking for a solution where you don't have to write...

```
\begin{ocg}{First layer}{oc1}{1}
A
\end{ocg}...
```

... for each character in the document.

I've tried using pymupdf, but I can't find a good way to keep the embedded fonts (subsets) while creating ocgs.

Is there an easy way to do this in latex and keep the documents clean and readable?

Comment: Must it be done in LaTeX directly, or can you post-process the PDF using other software? The un-limited versions of Acrobat Pro and DC have the capability to OCR a PDF and add a layer (you can also correct spelling, where the OCR misses). But it would not reliably parse math expressions.

Comment: What is an OCG ?

Comment: @PeterWilson Optional Content Groups, the official name for "PDF Layers" in the document whose visibility  can be set/unset by user action (via links in the document, switches in the viewer GUI) or by embedded JavaScript.

Comment: @PeterWilson Usage example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492768

Comment: It can be done in a pdf post-process. But I need the font-subsets to get through that process.